# How to hide child elements instead of deleting using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hide, parent-child, children, removechild

Here is the sample Javascript:

```
qwertyID.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    let button=e.target;
    button.classList.add("chosen");
    button.disabled="true";
    let letterFound=checkLetter(button);
    ol=document.getElementsByTagName('OL')[0];
    if (letterFound==null) {
        ol.lastChild.style.display="none";
        missed+=1;
    }
    checkWin();
});
```

Instead of deleting child elements from a parent, I want to hide them each time. The remove method deletes the child elements one after another. However, with the display property, it only removes a single element and none after that even if the condition is met again.

How do I get the rest of child elements to hide, when letterFound is equal to null? It works with the remove method but not the display hidden. But I don't want to necessarily delete the child elements.

Comment: If one of the answers helped solve your problem don't forget to select it as a an answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ol.lastChild` is the last child of `ol`, even if it's already hidden. So you're just hiding the same element every time.

You need to find the last child that's still visible and hide that. You can do that by looping from the end of the `childNodes` list.

```
for (let i = ol.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (ol.childNodes[i].style.display != "none") {
        ol.childNodes[i].style.display = "none";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like Barmar said, you're always hiding the last element, but you don't actually need to loop through your elements to find the last hidden one because you're already tracking the number of times the player has missed.

```
if (letterFound==null) {
    ol.childNodes[childNodes.length - 1 - missed].style = "none";
    missed += 1;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to do this solely with javascript.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of adding the class to the appropriate element. `ol.lastChild` will already have the class.

Comment: I've made edits to improve my answer and address the question correctly.